# Mail reader that displays any mbox file or Maildir

Tags: email

Is there a GUI-based mail reader that I can call with the path to an arbitrary mbox file or Maildir directory? In other words, a mail reader that does not insist on storing all mail in a single place in the file system? I'd like to store mail and other files organized by task or topic, for easier backup and sharing.

Answer (score 9):

man mutt

```
-f mailbox
Specify which mailbox to load.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about mutt, which I have used in the distant past. But nowadays I am used to GUI-based mail readers, so I don't think I could go back to terminal mode. I modified my question accordingly.

Comment: `-R     Open a mailbox in read-only mode.`

Answer (score 3):

Balsa (http://pawsa.fedorapeople.org/balsa/) can work with mailboxes (mbox or Maildir) anywhere in the file system. It's not perfect either (opening a mailbox from the command line doesn't work, although there's a documented option for this), but until now it's the best solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

Evolution allows you to add arbitrary mailboxes in either mbox or maildir format. It will still store its information in its own private store though.

Comment: Not quite perfect, but with a small support script it almost does what I need. Thanks! The solution I am testing consists of setting up an empty directory in Evolution as a Maildir store. Then I have a small script that removes everything from that directory and puts in a symbolic link to the Maildir I want to read. Then it runs evolution. The main limitation is that I can't open two Evolution instances for different Maildirs at the same time.